# video.js - width="100%" height="100%" is not working?

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

```html
<body>

<link href="//mysite.com/player/video-js/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//mysite.com/css/op.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="//mysite.com/video-js/video.min.js"></script>

<div align="center">
<video id="myvideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls
 preload="auto" poster="IMG-LINK"
data-setup="{}">
 <source src="VIDEO-LINK" type="video/mp4" width="100%" height="100%">
</video>

</body>
```

**how to fix this with JW Player is working perfect with Video.js that can't be 100% full scern**

Comment: If i remember correctly, the width and height must be applied to `video` not `source` and the value must be in pixels. See more here : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_width.asp

Comment: Like that is working, but the style css is not working anymore now is simple video

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
<video style="width: 100%; height: 100%" id="myvideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto" poster="IMG-LINK" data-setup="{}">
 <source src="VIDEO-LINK" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you put width="100%" height="100%" in "video" tag not in "source" tag.

```
<video id="myvideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls
 preload="auto" poster="IMG-LINK"
data-setup="{}" width="100%" height="100%">
 <source src="VIDEO-LINK" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is not working width="100%" height="100%"

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `fluid` option

```html
<video class="video-js" data-setup='{"fluid": true}'>
    <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<body>

<link href="//mysite.com/player/video-js/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//mysite.com/css/op.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="//mysite.com/video-js/video.min.js"></script>

<div align="center">
<video id="myvideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls
 preload="auto" poster="IMG-LINK"
data-setup="{}">
 <source src="VIDEO-LINK" type="video/mp4" width="100%" height="100%">
</video>

</body>
```

```
<video id="myvideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls
 preload="auto" poster="IMG-LINK"
data-setup="{}" width="100%" height="100%">
 <source src="VIDEO-LINK" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Please check images which I attached.

[image]

[image]